# How to manually generate video thumbnails?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, video, thumbnails

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to ask how to generate video thumbnaiils manually?

In some videos, the generated thumbnail is the logo of the company (in the very beggining of the video), and not the content itself I want.

Is there any option to add a manual thumbnail to a video in ubuntu 14.04? thanks in advance